# How to return the dimension of image if I had already add padding before ? in matlab

Tags: matlab, padding

```
W = ones(3);

padded = padarray(W,[1, 1],'symmetric','both');
```

ASK : dimension = 3x3

after padding = 5x5

can you help me, how to return the dimension back to 3x3 ?

Comment: Do you want to crop it back? Or resize? It not clear in your question

Answer (score 2):

If you padded symmetrically with `n` zeros you can just index back using `end`:

```
I_orig = I_padded(n+1:end-n,n+1:end-n);
```